# How to duplicate a Component/Control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicating components at Run-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239002/duplicating-components-at-run-time)

I have a `TMyControl` (`Control1`) with it's own properties/events.
How can I create a duplicate instanse `Control2` that will have *exactly* the same properties/events?

---

To be more specific, I would like to clone an existing `TADODataSet` with streaming fields (and some events):

```
object ADODataSet1: TADODataSet
  Connection = ADOConnection1
  CursorType = ctStatic
  AfterOpen = ADODataSet1AfterOpen
  CommandText = 'select top 10  * from Polls'
  Parameters = <>
  Left = 224
  Top = 40
  object ADODataSet1PollID: TGuidField
    FieldName = 'PollID'
    FixedChar = True
    Size = 38
  end
  object ADODataSet1Title: TWideStringField
    FieldName = 'Title'
    Size = 255
  end
  object ADODataSet1Description: TWideStringField
    FieldName = 'Description'
    Size = 4000
  end
  object ADODataSet1PollType: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'PollType'
  end
end
```

---

Since you closed this question, will you consider a duplicate if I ask a new question **"How to duplicate a `TADODataSet` with Persistent fields"**?

Comment: You can't in general. If Control1 has a non-empty Name property, then no other sibling is allowed to have the same value for that property.

Comment: @RobKennedy, It is possible to temporary set Name to empty string and restore it.

Comment: `TDataSet` isn't a `TControl`.

Comment: Look at `TClientDataSet` which has cloning capabilities.

Comment: @NGLN, The title says "Component/Control". I don't think there should be a difference. `WriteComponent`, `ReadComponent` works. but the events are not duplicated, nor the streaming fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code might give some direction:

```
unit Unit130;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm130 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    edit2: TEdit;
  public
  end;

var
  Form130: TForm130;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm130.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  component: TComponent;
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  RegisterClass(TEdit);
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    stream.WriteComponent(edit1);
    stream.Position := 0;
    component := stream.ReadComponent(nil);
    edit2 := component as TEdit;

    { this is necessary to make the following InsertComponent work }
    edit2.Name := 'Edit2';
    InsertComponent(edit2);

    edit2.Parent := Self;
    edit2.Top := edit2.Top + 30;
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Checking into it. Should I call `UnRegisterClass` before Button1Click exits? p.s: strangely I do not get an exception if I click the button more than once... (Edit2 is created with the same name more than once?)

Comment: Indeed! It seems quite possible to add a component with the same name as long as the newly added component doesn't have the container as its owner.

Comment: Couldn't help but to notice `Form130`...

Comment: @JerryDodge, indeed! Over the time the Delphi projects folder gets somewhat crowded - until you get a new system. BTW, the dpr was named Project124...

Answer (score 4):

Copy all property values.

There is no default mechanism for this. And there is a reason for it. The problem with your request is that you really do not want all settings duplicated. For instance: should it appear at the same parent at the same location and with the same dimensions? And even if yes: which of both should be on top?